# When you're collaborating with another group, how do you decide which one is the first author of the paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, authorship, collaboration, projects

Say, A and B are two PhD students working on the same project, and C is their supervisor. D and E are two students working on a similar project to A and B's, and F is D and E's supervisor. The other day C and F met and decided to collaborate. And now the project is about to end, so it's time to write a paper. A, B, D, and E all insist they should be the first author, and no one wants to be the fourth place. 
In this situation, how should the supervisors decide who's first?
And imagine this scenario: B writes the paper without letting anyone know, and then they show this paper to the two groups and ask for the other three people's data. Then does this automatically make B the first author?

Comment: You give no basis for a way to make a decision other than to have a big and unsatisfying fight. Work with people less ego driven, I guess. No, B is automatically a leech, or trying to be. Some fields just list people alphabetically, which always put me near the front, of course.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'ego driven'.

Comment: Certainly it does. Make C the lead author since s/he has a bit of scientific humility.

Comment: Sounds like there weren't enough discussions about the form of the collaboration before the project started... Some things to consider: Who did the most work, or the most important part of the work? Is this a field where joint first-authorship is recognized?

Comment: @Anyon, I think measures like "most work" or "most important" are just weapons to be employed with little basis in reality. "Initiator of the study" might have more validity. If people contribute differently to a whole, who is to say which is "most"? These sorts of fights are very unsatisfying for everyone and can be destructive. "First-authorship" fields are, IMO, being very foolish. It is easy enough to add a "contributions" section in which the _nature_ of the contribution of each is mentioned - not the quantity or quality, but the nature of it.

Comment: Of course, I recognize that I can't change the (dysfunctional) culture of a field not my own. But there are many solutions to this problem that are less annoying. In my field, no one thinks that my colleague, "Bella", contributed more than I did, being listed first, on a _joint_ paper. We worked together and shared ideas. The paper is good, so we deserve praise, or bad, so not.

Comment: You get them to do "paper, rock, scissors" or draw straws - it seems, at this point, that they sound like 5 year old's in a playground...

Comment: @Buffy It is what it is. I certainly agree that these fights aren't good for anyone, and that contribution sections are a good thing. Yet I do think that "most work" measures are more realistic than you give them credit for. They're not perfect, of course, but in the vast majority of papers I've been involved with, we've had a clear consensus about it. It gets murkier for say second and third authorships, but fights for those are much rarer. As for "initiator", in many fields that'd be understood as the PI, who by convention is often last author... Perhaps "driving force" could work.

Comment: Although I never saw that for more than two authors, there should be (depending on the journal) the possibility to mention that those authors contributed equally. See the 3rd answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41341/equal-author-contribution?rq=1

Comment: @David I've seen it done for up to three authors.

Comment: Wait - you have two professors and four grad students working in an area, and all they can come up with is one paper?

Comment: I find all this hypothetical language really distracting and obfuscating. Just say what happened.

Comment: @ Solar Mike That's offensive

Comment: @ Azor Ahai Because I'm asking a general question, not discussing a specific story.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, what's the problem?

Comment: @OhLook - well, if there is that much work to be done, in my experience there are more papers that can be written based on the work and fairly straightforward extensions of it. The short letter announcing the new concept. The longer paper with complete results in an area. The theory. An extension of the concept in a new direction. Modeling and simulation. All of a sudden it becomes pretty trivial to have first author papers for more people, and each would be able to articulate what they brought in particular to the broader work. And, no fights, because everyone has lots of work to do...